# Removing certain parts of a list structure in python

Tags: python, list

I'm making an interface in python with Tkinter that lets the end-user insert certain information that gets saved to a problem structure in an .R file.

The program also lets the user load .R files that contains the same type of structure for editing. Example structure:

```
global <- list(
const='
#define max 60
#define min 2.8
double ALPHA[max];
double OMEGA[min];
',
foobar='
double foo(double *condition, double num) {
return foo2(foo3(vars));   
}'
)
```

Say the user wanted to edit the item in the list named foobar. How can I make a function that removes just the foobar part?

In other words: Remove the information between the first and last parentheses in the following example.

```
Foo=("This is(( a() text)(( with unmatching ((parentheses()(")
```

Comment: I don't understand the connection between your description of the problem (matching between quotes?) and your example (matching between parentheses). Can you clarify?

Comment: If your question is about Python lists, please show a before and after example of the Python list.